# Using my iPad to remotely execute Powershell on my desktop PC

Tags: windows, powershell, ipad

Does anyone have instructions/resources/step by step guidance to enable me to use my iOS on my iPad to remotely continue developing some test driven development to execute Powershell session with Pester on my Win 10 desktop.

My sense of networking skills needs an upgrade as I wasn't sure which apps on both sides I need to configure and set up correctly.

Not sure if Powershell web feature does allow me this. The idea of doing this is to relax on my couch with the iPad instead of sitting at my desk using the desktop. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow , as are open ended questions - possibly better fit for  http://reddit.com/r/PowerShell or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ .  That said, is [Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092?mt=8) (NB. requires Windows Professional or Enterprise editions) an option? PS Web Access appears to be [Server 2012 and 2012 R2 only](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611(v=ws.11).aspx). But [iPowerShell](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipowershell-for-ios/id482104289?mt=8) claims PS/SSH support.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will follow up as suggested.